# Creating sub-components in JIRA

Tags: jira

I am trying to deploy JIRA for the first time. We have a system (chip), sub-system (component) and several sub-components. I see that out of the box, JIRA only allows components and not subcomponents.

Is there a way around this OR do we have to 'flatten' everything to component level in JIRA?

Answer (score 1):

Jira says that [there is no built-in feature for subcomponents](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-846):

> While we absolutely understand the logic behind many of the requests
>   for subcomponents, we strongly believe that our focus should be on
>   making Jira simpler and easier to use

However, there are add-ons available on the Marketplace to create subcompontents:

1. [Configuration Management Toolkit](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1211825/configuration-management-toolkit?hosting=server&tab=reviews)
2. [Subcomponents and Component Versions](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1211548/subcomponents-and-component-versions?hosting=server&tab=overview)

Answer (score 0):

You can try Components/Subcomponents/Bundle Versions [add-on](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.deniz.jira.versioning/server/overview). It also allows you to create virtual components for just categorization of real components and create a hierarchy of components. Users can pick from subcomponent tree on issue screens and query issues belonging to any level in the tree using `component in subcomponetsof()` JQL function. The add-on has also other features like 'Component Specific Versions', Bundles, Subprojects, gadgets, Version Graph. By the way, I'm one of the developers so I may be biassed. 
You can check our [user manual](https://denizoguz.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CBSV/User+Manual) for more details.
[image]

Comment: This should really be an out-of-box functionality.